# Sql query to Count Total Consecutive Years from latest year

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table Temp:

```
 CREATE TABLE Temp 
( 
  [ID]  [int],
  [Year]  [INT],
 )
**ID    Year**
1 2016
1   2016
1   2015
1   2012
1   2011
1   2010
2   2016
2   2015
2   2014
2   2012
2   2011
2   2010
2   2009
3   2016
3   2015
3   2004
3   1999
4   2016
4   2015
4   2014
4   2010
5   2016
5   2014
5   2013
```

I want to calculate the total consecutive years starting from the most recent Year.
Result should look like this:

```
ID  Total Consecutive Yrs
1   2
2   3
3   2
4   3
5   1
```

Comment: but ID 1 has 2 consecutive years, twice... how do you handle that? Also, what have you tried?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select ID,
   -- returns a sequence without gaps for consecutive years
   first_value(year) over (partition by ID order by year desc) - year +1 as x, 
   -- returns a sequence without gaps
   row_number() over (partition by ID order by year desc) as rn
from Temp
```

e.g. for ID=1:

```
1   2016    1   1
1   2015    2   2
1   2012    5   3
1   2011    6   4
1   2010    7   5
```

As long as there's no gap, both sequences increase the same.

Now check for equal sequences and count the rows:

```
with cte as 
 (
   select ID,
      -- returns a sequence without gaps for consecutive years
      first_value(year) over (partition by ID order by year desc) - year + 1 as x, 
      -- returns a sequence without gaps
      row_number() over (partition by ID order by year desc) as rn
   from Temp

 ) 
select ID, count(*)
from cte
where x = rn  -- no gap
group by ID
```

Edit:

Based on your *year zero* comment:

```
with cte as 
 (
   select ID, year,
      -- returns a sequence without gaps for consecutive years
      first_value(year) over (partition by ID order by year desc) - year + 1 as x, 
      -- returns a sequence without gaps
      row_number() over (partition by ID order by year desc) as rn
   from Temp

 ) 
select ID, 
   -- remove the year zero from counting
   sum(case when year <> 0 then 1 else 0 end)
from cte
where x = rn
group by ID
```

Comment: When the year is zero, the result also should be zero. But in this query it is returning a 1 which is an error.

Comment: What do you mean by *When the year is zero*? There's nothing like that in your sample & expected result.

Comment: Yes my bad i forgot to add this to the sample. I mean when ID = 6 and Year = 0. Say this line is also added to the above sample. Then the result should be id = 0 and Total Consecutive Years = 0.

Comment: @genie: But what does a year zero mean?

Comment: I just generate the sample again i guess:ID Year
1 2016
1 2015
1 2012
1 2011
1 2010
2 2016
2 2015
2 2014
2 2012
2 2011
2 2010
2 2009
3 2016
3 2015
3 2004
3 1999
4 2016
4 2015
4 2014
4 2010
5 2016
5 2014
5 2013
6 0                                                                                                                                 The result set should look like: ID Total Consecutive Yrs
1 2
2 3
3 2
4 3
5 1
6 0

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using window functions:

```
select id, count(distinct year)
from (select t.*,
             dense_rank() over (partition by id order by year + seqnum desc) as grp
      from (select t.*,
                   dense_rank() over (partition by id order by year desc) as seqnum
            from temp t
           ) t
     ) t
where grp = 1
group by id;
```

This assumes that "most recent year" is per id.

Comment: Doesn't work as expected, simply returns one row per ID with the latest year and counts that row, always resulting in `1`.

Comment: @dnoeth . . . Yes, that was an incomplete thought.  It should be fixed now.

Answer (score 1):

You can use lead and get this counts as below:

```
Select top (1) with ties Id, RowN as [Total Consecutive Years] from (
    Select *, Num = case when ([year]- lead(year) over(partition by Id order by [Year] desc) > 1) then 0 else 1 end 
        , RowN = Row_Number() over (partition by Id order by [Year] desc)
    from temp
) a
where a.Num = 0
order by row_number() over(partition by Id order by RowN)
```

Output as below:

```
+----+-------------------------+
| Id | Total Consecutive Years |
+----+-------------------------+
|  1 |                       2 |
|  2 |                       3 |
|  3 |                       2 |
|  4 |                       3 |
|  5 |                       1 |
+----+-------------------------+
```

Comment: Crazy logic :-) But it fails when there's only an ID with a single row.

Answer (score 0):

Gordon Linoff,
Your code is awesome!
Your code pulls consecutive years from the most recent year.
I modified it to pull overall max consecutive years.
Posted here in case anyone else needs it:

```
--overall max consecutive years
select id,max(yr_cnt) max_consecutive_years
from (
select id, grp,count(seqnum) yr_cnt
from (select t.*,
             dense_rank() over (partition by id order by year + seqnum desc) as grp           
      from (select t.*,    
            dense_rank() over (partition by id order by year desc) as seqnum 
            from temp t    
           ) t
     ) t
group by id,grp) t2
group by id;
```