# SQL code for counting consecutive years - syntax error msg in code

Tags: mysql, syntax-error

I'm a heavy MS Access user, but still a novice with SQL. I need to count consecutive years in a table and am attempting to use SQL code provided on a previous post in Stack in order to count consecutive years by ID. My table name is "TEMP" and two field names are "ID" (ten-digit field stored as short text) and a 4-digit field named "YEAR" (stored as a number). I'm attempting to use a solution provided at [Sql query to Count Total Consecutive Years from latest year](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45151326/sql-query-to-count-total-consecutive-years-from-latest-year) but I'm getting a syntax error in the code on "over"

A sample of the data:

```
ID          YEAR
0363267020  1982
0374650010  1982
0395373010  1982
0397175020  1982
0427746010  1982
0435187010  1985
0435187010  1984
0435187010  1982
0445237010  2017
0445237010  2016
0445237010  2015
0445237010  2014
0445237010  2013
0445237010  2012
0445237010  2010
0445237010  2009
0445237010  2008
0445237010  2005
```

The overall solution is to enable a count of consecutive of giving. So for above, the first 8 IDs wouldn't yet any counts, but the 9th ID would yield a result of 9. Is anyone able to assist?

In the end, I could export to Excel, but then it becomes a much more manual process and I'm hoping to build something that is more automatic (the table has more than 20,000 records).

I've also tried the following module, but am having trouble building a query to pull the data out.

Option Compare Database

```
With CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("TEMP")
Do Until ID.EOF
    If !YEAR = strPrevious Then
        Debug.Print strPrevious, lngCount
        lngCount = 0
    Else
        strPrevious = !YEAR
        lngCount = lngCount + 1
    End If
Loop
End With
```

CODE from [Sql query to Count Total Consecutive Years from latest year](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45151326/sql-query-to-count-total-consecutive-years-from-latest-year)

```
select ID,
first_value(year) over (partition by ID order by year desc) - year +1 as x, 
row_number() over (partition by ID order by year desc) as rn

from Temp

with cte as 
(
select ID, year,

first_value(year) over (partition by ID order by year desc) - year + 1 as x, 

row_number() over (partition by ID order by year desc) as rn

from Temp

) 
select ID, 

sum(case when year <> 0 then 1 else 0 end)
from cte
where x = rn
group by ID
```

I get the syntax error in the SQL query code. When I have attempted a query to work with the module, I continue to receive various error messages.

Comment: Are you using MySQL OR SQLServer? They are not the same and in many cases the syntax is different

Comment: Thank you for looking at my question. I am using SQL via MS Access (so not MySQL).